# IPTABLES blocking ports that should be open

Tags: iptables, centos7

I'm using centos7 and have the following rules set up:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [6:394]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [42:6917]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 433 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

But for some reason port 25 isn't working when I try to send emails. If I disable iptables all is fine, so I know it has something to do with that. What am I doing wrong here?  When I do a port scan the only ports that show as open is SSH, HTTP, FTP, and MYSQL.

Comment: Is firewalld installed and configured too ?

Comment: No, I'm just using iptables.  Besides, everything works when I disable iptables but starts blocking when I enable iptables.  So I'm pretty sure it's iptables.

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  You say port 25 isn't working when **sending** emails, but you don't have any rule to permit return-half connections when doing that.  So why are you surprised that it doesn't work?

Comment: firewalld is just a front end to iptables.

Comment: Do yourself a favor: Don't try to write your own firewall rules using bad Internet tutorials, at least not until you understand iptables well. Just use firewalld; it will create a perfectly secure firewall to spec.

Comment: I tried firewalld and it caused nothing but problems.  I'm trying halfgaar's solution to see how it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason for these?:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
```

It looks like you're blocking all new (`SYN`) connections? I'm surpised anything works.

I would just do this as the first entry:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `RELATED,`, but apart from that, I agree - this will make a much more sensible ruleset.

Comment: He does want FTP open, so `RELATED` may be needed.

Comment: so drop those 3 lines and go with yours instead?  They where there to try to keep flood attacks from happening.

Comment: Yes, that line instead of your 3. As for flood attacks, that can be tricky. You can implement connection rate limiting with iptables for instance, but that may give you more headache than anything else. And real DOSing you can only 'fix' by having an upstream router null-route you.

Comment: Well, it's a cloud vps in ha with as much mitigation you can possibly get layers 1-6.  I do get access to a configurable firewall upstream of the vps, but I haven't messed with it at all yet.  I guess trying to do all this on the box itself is probably overkill.